# How to construct a mesh from given edge points?

Tags: math, mesh, cad, cg

I have some points on the edge(left image), and I want to construct a mesh(right), Is there any good algorithm to achieve it? many thanks!

image can see here http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/large/6a2c8e2bjw1dk8jr3t7eaj.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, see [Delauney triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).  Look at this project: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/triangulate/triangulate.html.

Edited because my original had too few details on edge-flipping, and when I tried to provided those details I found the TRIANGULATE project.

Answer (score 0):

If the region is flat or quasi-flat look for Ear Clipping approach (http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf). In the case of curved surface you need point inside the region and therefore you may need Constrained Delaunay Triangulation (otherwise some edges may not be included in the triangulation).

Answer (score 0):

There is `delaunayn` function in [`geometry` package for `R` language (see doc)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geometry/geometry.pdf)
It takes an array of boundary points (as in your case) to create a Delaunay mesh on it.

You could also save your geometry into some well-known format, and use [one of  mesh generators](http://www.robertschneiders.de/meshgeneration/software.html).